# Python - User input to determine a condtion in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

Why does the code below produce an infinite loop? If I hard code the value of y to be equal to 10 it doesn't go on forever, yet if I enter 10 through user input it does.

```
x = 0
y = raw_input("Enter a Number: ")

while x <= y:
    x = x + 1
    if x %2 == 0:
        print x
    else:
        print "odd"
```

Comment: Use `while x <= int(y):`.  `raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer.

Comment: @vaultah, it's not exactly a duplicate. The asker simply doesn't know that `raw_input()` returns strings regardless of the input.

Comment: Another dupe target: [How can I read inputs as integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/2301450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to transform your y value, which is now a string, to a number.

For example like:

```
y = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: Additionally, instead of using `while x <= y:`, you can use `for x in range(0, y+1):`

Comment: I feel like they should hand out dunce badges for questions like these. I'm face palming right now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on @SiggyF's answer, modify your code to this to get rid of unnecessary lines:

```
y = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
for x in range(0, y+1):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print(x)
    else:
        print("odd")
```